# Union columns in same table and show sum of two columns based on the ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find a query that can help me doing the following, I have one table like bellow

```
ID1  VALUE1  ID2  VALUE2
=========================
1   1         2     2
1   2         1     2
2   3         2     4
2   4         3     5 
3   6         1     5
4   2         1     1
```

I'm looking for

```
ID  VALUE1  VALUE2
=========================
1   3         8
2   7         6
3   6         5
4   2         0
```

Basically, search in ID1 and shows sum in Value1 and search same ID in ID2 and shows sum of Value2

I tried

```
SELECT
ID1 as ID,
SUM(VALUE1) AS VALUE1,
SUM(VALUE2) AS VALUE2
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID1;
```

but the query above does not show what I want.

I made this where it union both IDs

```
SELECT ID1 as ID from TABLE
UNION
SELECT ID2 from TABLE
```

but then I do't know how to use the created columns to search on Value1 and Value2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `union all` to combine the four columns into a more reasonable format.  Then aggregate with `group by`:

```
select id, sum(value1), sum(value2)
from ((select id1 as id, value1 as val1, 0 as val2 from t
      ) union all
      (select id2, 0, value2 from t
      )
     ) tt
group by id;
```